# SQL Count for each grouping

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

So I am writing a SQL statement for the following. List the count of patients for each insurance code.

here is my SQL Statement.

```
SELECT INSURANCE.INS_ID, PATIENT.MPI_LastName
FROM PHYSICIAN 
     INNER JOIN 
           (PATIENT INNER JOIN 
                    (INSURANCE INNER JOIN VISIT 
                       ON INSURANCE.INS_ID = VISIT.VIS_InsuranceCode
                    ) 
             ON PATIENT.MPI_NUMBER = VISIT.VIS_MPINum
           ) 
           ON PHYSICIAN.PHY_ID = VISIT.VIS_Phys
ORDER BY INSURANCE.INS_ID;
```

I do not know how to write a SQL to count the Patients for each insurance code. without duplicate records being counted.

[image: I need a count of patients for each code]

Comment: Duplicate record would mean counting the same `MPI_LastName` more than once?

Comment: Use `count(distinct lastname)` with `group by insid`...

Comment: The question asks for the count of patients by insurance code, not by patient name. Drop the patient name column, add a COUNT and a GROUP BY.

Comment: If the patient has a unique identifier (`MPI_NUMBER`??) then you should `COUNT(DISTINCT [Unique Id])` instead of the last name - I assume some people, especially family members, share the same last name.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT INSURANCE.INS_ID, count(distinct PATIENT.MPI_LastName) as count 
  FROM VISIT    
  JOIN PATIENT  
        ON PATIENT.MPI_NUMBER = VISIT.VIS_MPINum
  JOIN INSURANCE 
        ON INSURANCE.INS_ID   = VISIT.VIS_InsuranceCode 
 GROUP BY INSURANCE.INS_ID


  SELECT VISIT.VIS_InsuranceCode, count(distinct PATIENT.MPI_LastName) as count 
  FROM VISIT    
  JOIN PATIENT  
        ON PATIENT.MPI_NUMBER = VISIT.VIS_MPINum
 GROUP BY VISIT.VIS_InsuranceCode
```

Comment: Don't hate the messenger, but there is no explanation and the last name is probably not unique. You are taught during the review process to downvote code only answers.

Comment: @maraca  Not unique - that is the purpose of the distinct.  There is a review training?  Do you know that answer is wrong?  If so why not post a proper answer?  Cheers

Comment: I wouldn't down vote this answer but it is simple to edit your answer and add some details. People often change their mind after they see an explanation. Also - personally I wouldn't use a reserved word (count) for a generated field name in your query

Comment: @dbmitch So it went from 9 lines to 5.  I will let the OP give it a try.

Comment: @Paparazzi - I think @maraca was referring to the possibility that more than one patient would have the same last name within the same `INS_ID` which means that performing a distinct count on that field would not be appropriate. I didn't down vote however, do you really consider this a quality answer?

Comment: When you hover over the down vote - the criteria says "This answer is not useful". I believe this does not meet THAT criteria, so I'd argue that downvoting for another reason is making up your own criteria.

Comment: @Nicarus So?   That is the stated question.

Comment: What? I was saying that people who DID downvote were NOT using StackOverflow criteria. Now I'm not sure why I bothered to join in this pointless discussion

Comment: I am using access and it does not like the syntax on count(distinct PATIENT.MPI_LastName)

Comment: @ByronImportanteDavis It only said SQL when  I answered.  Answer is only as good as the question.

Comment: @Paparazzi I am new to this please forgive me What other information do you need?